# Is there a way to make an all white/no colored render?

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have rendered the following scene, is there a way to render the scene as as white/all grey without assigning materials? I think there's a way to do it in compositing using the ambient occlusion node.

[image]

Comment: You must mean something other than graytones, because that simply to select the BW instead of RGB in the Output Properties.  You might consider adding more detail to your question.

Comment: @james_t sorry for the confusion, I essentially want the scene to be a numeral/grey/white color similar to if your watching a vfx breakdown. I tried changing the output to BW and it still came it in color which is weird

Comment: add a color ramp in the compositor?

Comment: Yes I would say use the Compositor with desaturation etc

Comment: changing the output to BW: actually if you hit F12 it will still render in color, but if you use the ctl-F12 to render and store the output frames, it will be in B&W.  Quirky